# A question about generating low frequency sine waves by a soundcard

Tags: audio, sound-card

As a part of a bigger experiment I need to control the frequency of a speaker by a PC through a MOSFET amplifier. The rest is someone else will use that speaker output for some mechanical application to push air pressure ect. I need to deal with the electrical part.

Here is the power MOSFET amplifier's input output ports:

[image]

Currently a manual function generator(set to 2Hz 2Vrms currently) is coupled to the sym input. I guess this sym is in line level.

Unfortunately I couldn't find the datasheet of the above MOSFET amplifier since it is bit old one.

My freq of interest for sine wave generation is from ***0.1Hz to 200Hz***. As you see in the below figures a MOSFET amplifier is powering  8 0hm speaker. I also need to monitor the frequency going into the power amplifier by a DAQ or scope.

So far I tried the system in Figure 2 below:

[image]

**Regarding Figure 2:**
From a PC software like Python, I can control the PWM output of Arduino then to an active filter which converts the PWM to a constant voltage. And an old obsolete part VCO(ICL8038 ) converts the voltage to frequency. I have some problems with this. One is one cannot set the frequency very precisely because the PWM has 255 step resolution. ICL8038 sine output is a bit deformed at low frequencies. And also it is not possible to set a single cap which can give a range of 0.1Hz to 200Hz(One needs to change the cap for this range).

So I thought maybe it is not necessary to use all of these. I thought the system in Figure 1 can be used. I mean directly coupling the audio output(I guess it is line level) of the PC to the amplifier's line input(maybe through a buffer of an amplifier).

My questions are:

1-) Do you think I can generate better sine waves comparing to ICL8038 for the range from 0.1Hz to 100Hz by using the soundcard of the PC?

2-) In that case(Figure 1), would I need a buffer or an amp between the power MOSFET and the PC audio port? Basically for the Figure 1, do I need another interface?

(I also read about DDS Synthesizers, but maybe I might not need that for this application if the PC sound card would suffice)

Comment: Before you do anything else, you need to find the manual for the amplifier. Then read it closely. The odds are very good that it will not respond below about 20 Hz.

Comment: And IIRC a soundcard output is AC coupled, so it has a low-frequency cutoff too.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast But it does even for 0.5Hz. It is already used. My question is about the sine generation and coupling to its units. Experimentally when a bench function gen is used there is no problem. I just need to automatize it py a PC.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen Maybe I should go back to old ICL8038 solution if the PC audio cannot output down to 0.1Hz,

Comment: For this I would use a bench function generator with LXI interface. I don't think any standard sound card will provide output down to anywhere near 100mHz.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany The generator in use is http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/499058.pdf?_ga=1.129729036.1263433037.1467971694 It has a USB port but I dont know what is that used for.

Comment: Well, it says right on the datasheet that it uses [SCPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Commands_for_Programmable_Instruments) through the USB. No isolation but otherwise as suggested.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thanks maybe I have been swimming in the wrong waters. I will try to learn how to control this with SCPI commands even though the manual doesnt tell much about the commands in detail https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/13f8/0900766b813f8f52.pdf I have to be sure it is programmable version first though.